# How to archive order in shopify using shopify_app gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

I have implemented a simple Shopify app using shopify_app gem, here we are doing simple modifications to order like adding tags depending upon the order fulfillment status. Is there a way to archive the order from the Shopify app using shopify_app gem?, Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the order status to be closed, freeing up your algorithms to only deal with open orders. Achieves the goal I getting orders done with out of the way and archived. There is no actual 'set the status to archived', but the front-end admin gives that illusion to keep merchants satisfied.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your time to share your thoughts, I didn't see any status column in order to flip it to closed. Could you help me with how you closing it?